# ggplot2 the tick of left bottom corner on x-axis is missing

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I used the following code to set ticks of x-axis:
scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("0", "25", "50","75","100"), labels=c("-5000", "-2500", "TSS","+2500","+5000"))
However,  the tick of left bottom corner on x-axis is missing ("-5000"). Thanks!
 [image]

***UPDATE:***

code is as follows:

```
 library(ggplot2)  
setwd("E:\\")
group<-rep("xxxx",200)
window_index<-rep(1,200)
methy<-rep(0.0001,200)

dev.new(width=5, height=5)   


mydata <- c(2.69523,2.68113,2.701,2.71295,2.70934,2.7296,2.72514,2.68913,2.73231,2.71893,2.69485,2.68669,2.68183,2.66985,2.67812,2.7338,2.73466,2.8215,2.85903,2.90604,2.90006,2.89354,2.8911,2.97816,2.97491,2.87716,2.92016,2.86783,2.89455,2.83303,2.82433,2.79304,2.75092,2.76338,2.75429,2.70159,2.70007,2.73415,2.75342,2.81465,2.82124,2.80865,2.89053,2.90289,2.94132,2.97236,2.92759,2.92887,2.82978,2.91186,2.93556,2.92286,3.1038,3.11793,3.02738,3.09251,3.03509,2.83917,2.88059,2.89928,2.90047,2.91454,2.97956,2.87407,2.80076,2.83614,2.94722,2.86846,2.88684,2.8567,2.92221,3.01379,2.81978,2.8499,2.84203,2.83075,2.88386,2.8297,2.86195,2.79944,2.75654,2.79975,2.76778,2.80503,2.8923,2.84483,2.86865,2.93443,2.93266,2.91609,2.84964,2.80428,2.80971,2.8714,2.8648,2.95276,2.96739,2.92146,2.84643,2.8208)
for(ii in 1:100)
{
  group[ii]<-"aaa"
  window_index[ii]<-ii
  methy[ii]<-mydata[ii]
}


mydata <- c(2.34237,2.34268,2.35625,2.36485,2.3783,2.37418,2.35682,2.36853,2.3608,2.3571,2.35735,2.35252,2.35252,2.33272,2.34562,2.32457,2.34611,2.34031,2.33919,2.34066,2.33347,2.32424,2.33652,2.32585,2.29247,2.27918,2.25712,2.26037,2.24051,2.22711,2.21825,2.18171,2.16823,2.14479,2.10432,2.09132,2.05602,2.03091,2.03254,1.97737,1.95969,1.91187,1.85156,1.80697,1.73918,1.66702,1.60589,1.5536,1.51319,1.50754,1.49283,1.4818,1.51782,1.55003,1.6109,1.69999,1.78381,1.85273,1.94049,1.97149,1.99167,2.01945,2.05049,2.0917,2.12086,2.15047,2.17492,2.18193,2.18286,2.21,2.23119,2.24763,2.23394,2.24945,2.28581,2.29289,2.3308,2.32653,2.33957,2.33636,2.33611,2.34112,2.33125,2.34421,2.34622,2.36038,2.42041,2.44383,2.43497,2.40866,2.3726,2.34923,2.33929,2.33217,2.31134,2.32536,2.32067,2.31716,2.31672,2.28108) 
for(ii in 1:100)
{
  group[ii+100]<-"bbb"
  window_index[ii+100]<-ii
  methy[ii+100]<-mydata[ii]
}

mydata<-data.frame(group=group,window_index=window_index,methy=methy)

ggplot(mydata, aes(x = window_index, y =methy , colour = group)) + geom_line()  + 
ggtitle("ATs") +  xlab("")+  ylab("level")+ 
scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("0", "25", "50","75","100"), labels=c("-5000", "-2500", "TSS","+2500","+5000"))+ 
theme( legend.position="bottom")+ theme(legend.title=element_blank())
```

Comment: Please post a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). I could not reproduce with: `ggplot(data.frame(y=rnorm(10), x=c("0", "25", "50","75","100"), g=rep(c("a","b"), each=5)), aes(x,y, color=g, group=g)) + geom_line() +  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("0", "25", "50","75","100"), labels=c("-5000", "-2500", "TSS","+2500","+5000"))`

Comment: You could have just posted dput(mydata) and the ggplot code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems to me the x scale is continuous. THe following fixes the left break,

```
scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0, 25, 50, 75, 100), 
   labels=c("-5000", "-2500", "TSS","+2500","+5000"), 
   expand=c(0,0), lim=c(0,100))
```

Comment: i believe the problem you had was that scale_discrete interpreted your data as factor levels, which run from 1 to N, hence 0 was dropped.

Comment: Yes. Changed breaks=c("0", "25", "50","75","100") to be breaks=c("1", "25", "50","75","100"), it worked.